# Angular - Add active style in header dropdown

Tags: css, angular

I´m trying to add active style in buttons when the routes matches.

The dropdown menu elements add active style properly but parent element does not have this style.

```
<div class="navbar-custom-menu">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li>
              <a href="#" class="navbar-brand" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">{{'entity' |
              translate}} <span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                <li [routerLinkActive]="['active']" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact:true}"><a
                    [routerLink]="['/entidad/listado']"><i class="fa fa-list"></i> {{'list' | translate}}</a></li>
                <li [routerLinkActive]="['active']" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact:true}"><a
                    [routerLink]="['/entidad/formulario']"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> {{'new' | translate}}</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
    </ul>
    </div>
```

So the question is: How can i add active element in parent

```
<a href="#" class="navbar-brand" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">{{'entity' | translate}} <span class="caret"></span></a>
```

when ul dropdown menu elements is selected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using the `isActive` method of the `router`:

https://angular.io/api/router/Router#isActive

To apply the `active` class to your parent `<a>` tag when either of the dropdown menu's routes are active, you could add a `[class.active]` attribute, as such:

```
[class.active]="router.isActive('/entidad/listado', true) || router.isActive('/entidad/formulario', true)"
```

So on your parent element, it would look like this:

```
<a href="#" class="navbar-brand" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false"
  [class.active]="router.isActive('/entidad/listado', true) || router.isActive('/entidad/formulario', true)">
    {{'entity' | translate}} <span class="caret"></span>
</a>
```